# Endless execution when calling `save(object, depth)` method on Neoj4Session instance

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

After database migration from neo4j 3.5. * to 4.1.* server and Spring Neo4j Data dependencies update to version 5.3.4.RELEASE, the `save (object, depth)` method stopped working. It looks like it hangs at this place:

```java
neo4jSession.save(actualRelation, 0); // actualRelation is an instance of ProfileParentGroupRelation class
```

*ProfileParentGroupRelation.java:*

```java
@RelationshipEntity(type = "HAS_PARENT")
public class ProfileParentGroupRelation extends TimespanRelationship {

    @StartNode
    private Profile profile;

    @EndNode
    private Group parent;
    private List<Integer> userRoles;
    
    public ProfileParentGroupRelation() {
    }
    public Profile getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }
    public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
        this.profile = profile;
    }
    public Group getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    public void setParent(Group parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public List<Integer> getUserRoles() {
        return userRoles;
    }
    public void setUserRoles(List<Integer> userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }
}
```

*pom.xml:*

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.infotemp</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-db-module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>neo4j-db-module</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- <spring.version>5.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version> -->
        <spring.version>5.2.11.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Neo4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphaware.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>uuid</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.58.19</version>
        </dependency>
   
    
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>Neumann-SR4</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I suspect that the problem is in the call "neo4jSession.save()", because I’ve raised same problem in other places where this call is used.

Please help me to understand the reason of the following problem. Any help would be appreciated.

---

### UPDATES:

*Source:*

```java
System.out.println("Start of [neo4jSession.save(actualRelation,0)]");           
neo4jSession.save(actualRelation,0);    
System.out.println("End of [neo4jSession.save(actualRelation,0)]");
```

*Neo4j Logs:*

```
Start of [neo4jSession.save(actualRelation,0)]
2020-11-19 16:37:24,296 DEBUG .ogm.session.delegates.SaveEventDelegate:  96 - visiting: com.infotemp.neo4j.model.relationship.ProfileParentGroupRelation@c3
2020-11-19 16:37:24,297 DEBUG .ogm.session.delegates.SaveEventDelegate:  96 - visiting: com.infotemp.neo4j.model.Profile@2fbc66a8
2020-11-19 16:37:24,297 DEBUG .ogm.session.delegates.SaveEventDelegate: 104 - already visited: com.infotemp.neo4j.model.relationship.ProfileParentGroupRelation@c3
2020-11-19 16:37:24,297 DEBUG .ogm.session.delegates.SaveEventDelegate: 178 - dirty: com.infotemp.neo4j.model.Profile@2fbc66a8
2020-11-19 16:37:24,299 DEBUG .ogm.session.delegates.SaveEventDelegate:  96 - visiting: Group [labels=[Project], displayName=Sub-project #3 [edited], subdomain=null, secondaryType=7, description=test, allowAccountProfiles=null, locationRadius=null, locationTracking=false, parentGroups=null, addresses=null, phoneNumbers=null, emails=null, historyData=null, actionSets=null, emailTemplates=null, approvalProcesses=null, reportTypes=null, profiles=[com.infotemp.neo4j.model.relationship.ProfileParentGroupRelation@c3], impotTemplates=null]
2020-11-19 16:37:24,299 DEBUG .ogm.session.delegates.SaveEventDelegate: 104 - already visited: com.infotemp.neo4j.model.relationship.ProfileParentGroupRelation@c3
2020-11-19 16:37:24,300 DEBUG .ogm.session.delegates.SaveEventDelegate: 178 - dirty: Group [labels=[Project], displayName=Sub-project #3 [edited], subdomain=null, secondaryType=7, description=test, allowAccountProfiles=null, locationRadius=null, locationTracking=false, parentGroups=null, addresses=null, phoneNumbers=null, emails=null, historyData=null, actionSets=null, emailTemplates=null, approvalProcesses=null, reportTypes=null, profiles=[com.infotemp.neo4j.model.relationship.ProfileParentGroupRelation@c3], impotTemplates=null]
2020-11-19 16:37:24,300 DEBUG .ogm.session.delegates.SaveEventDelegate: 178 - dirty: com.infotemp.neo4j.model.relationship.ProfileParentGroupRelation@c3
HAS_PARENT: f00e48cc-7f31-4df3-b1f7-3b3eb1ce971e
2020-11-19 16:37:24,300 DEBUG  org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper: 124 - context initialised with 0 relationships
2020-11-19 16:37:24,301 DEBUG  org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper: 358 - visiting: com.infotemp.neo4j.model.Profile@2fbc66a8
2020-11-19 16:37:24,301 DEBUG  org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper: 305 - com.infotemp.neo4j.model.Profile@2fbc66a8 has changed
2020-11-19 16:37:24,302 DEBUG  org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper: 284 - at horizon 0: com.infotemp.neo4j.model.Profile@2fbc66a8 
2020-11-19 16:37:24,302 DEBUG  org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper: 358 - visiting: Group [labels=[Project], displayName=Sub-project #3 [edited], subdomain=null, secondaryType=7, description=test, allowAccountProfiles=null, locationRadius=null, locationTracking=false, parentGroups=null, addresses=null, phoneNumbers=null, emails=null, historyData=null, actionSets=null, emailTemplates=null, approvalProcesses=null, reportTypes=null, profiles=[com.infotemp.neo4j.model.relationship.ProfileParentGroupRelation@c3], impotTemplates=null]
2020-11-19 16:37:24,302 DEBUG  org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper: 305 - Group [labels=[Project], displayName=Sub-project #3 [edited], subdomain=null, secondaryType=7, description=test, allowAccountProfiles=null, locationRadius=null, locationTracking=false, parentGroups=null, addresses=null, phoneNumbers=null, emails=null, historyData=null, actionSets=null, emailTemplates=null, approvalProcesses=null, reportTypes=null, profiles=[com.infotemp.neo4j.model.relationship.ProfileParentGroupRelation@c3], impotTemplates=null] has changed
2020-11-19 16:37:24,303 DEBUG  org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper: 284 - at horizon 0: Group [labels=[Project], displayName=Sub-project #3 [edited], subdomain=null, secondaryType=7, description=test, allowAccountProfiles=null, locationRadius=null, locationTracking=false, parentGroups=null, addresses=null, phoneNumbers=null, emails=null, historyData=null, actionSets=null, emailTemplates=null, approvalProcesses=null, reportTypes=null, profiles=[com.infotemp.neo4j.model.relationship.ProfileParentGroupRelation@c3], impotTemplates=null] 
2020-11-19 16:37:24,303 DEBUG  org.neo4j.ogm.context.EntityGraphMapper: 974 - context-new: (-6)-[164:HAS_PARENT]->(-7)
2020-11-19 16:37:24,304 DEBUG drivers.bolt.transaction.BoltTransaction:  61 - No current transaction, starting a new one
2020-11-19 16:37:24,317 DEBUG drivers.bolt.transaction.BoltTransaction:  64 - Native transaction: org.neo4j.driver.internal.InternalTransaction@2c82a47b
2020-11-19 16:37:24,318 DEBUG o4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest: 178 - Request: UNWIND $rows as row MERGE (n:`GroupSettings`:`Profile`{uuid: row.props.uuid}) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, $type as type with params {type=node, rows=[{nodeRef=-6, props={mustUseProjectForReports=false, roundingAmountPauseEndTime=null, allowAutoPauseOverwrite=false, minReportPauseLength=null, dateFormat=null, minReportLength=null, roundingTypeReportStartTime=null, language=null, uuid=0bf5124e-ee46-439c-a98b-3d162bfd3a21, allowReportsToTime=null, sumLeaveLTEOvertimePool=null, honorificSuffix=null, warningTypeReportClocking=null, registrationSourceType=null, familyName=null, roundingAmountReportStartTime=null, givenName=null, timeZone=null, overtimeCorrectionAmount=null, settingsInheritanceStrategy=null, personalNumber=null, creationDate=null, sumVacationLTEVacationPool=null, allowReportsFromTime=null, userRoles=null, approvalNotifications=null, onlyFullDayVacation=null, roundingTypePauseEndTime=null, roundingAmountReportEndTime=null, unique=null, userUuid=f00e48cc-7f31-4df3-b1f7-3b3eb1ce971e, roundingTypePauseStartTime=null, actions=[1000000010002, 2000000010002, 4000100000001, 4000100000002, 4000100000003, 4000100000004, 8000100000001, 8000100000002, 8000100000003, 8000100000004, 9000100000001, 12000000000002, 16000100000002, 17000100000002, 4000000000001, 4000000000002, 4000000000003, 4000000000004, 4000000010003, 5000000010002, 6000000000001, 6000000000002, 6000000000003, 6000000000004, 6000100000001, 6000100000004, 6000100000002, 6000100000003, 8000000000001, 8000000000002, 8000000000003, 8000000000004, 8000000010003, 9000000000001, 14000000000002, 16000100000001, 16000100000003, 16000100000004, 17000000000002, 1000000000001, 1000000000002, 1000000000003, 1000000000004, 2000000000001, 2000000000003, 2000000000002, 2000000000004, 5000000000001, 5000000000002, 5000000000003, 5000000000004, 5000100000003, 9000000000002, 9000200000002, 18000000000000, 13000000000001, 14000000000001, 14000000000003, 14000000000004], gender=null, displayName=null, formatted=null, warningForClockingReport=null, hasAllInclusiveContract=null, reportPauseLengthProblem=null, allowPaidPausesInReports=false, roundingTypeReportEndTime=null, numberFormat=null, autoCreateReports=false, minVacationLength=null, maxDailyReportLength=null, chipId=null, roundingAmountPauseStartTime=null, maxReportLength=null, onlyClockingReports=false, availableLoginMethods=null, unique3=null, honorificPrefix=null, unique1=null, unique2=null, birthDate=null, allowReportsInFuture=7258118400000, highlightTargetTimeDifferences=0, warningForClockingDay=null, vacationCorrectionAmount=null, allowReportsInPast=true, maxReportPauseLength=null, timeFormat=null, hintStatus=null, maxVacationLength=null, autoSaveDesktop=null, middleName=null}}]}
2020-11-19 16:37:24,332 DEBUG o4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest: 178 - Request: UNWIND $rows as row MERGE (n:`Group`:`GroupSettings`:`Project`{uuid: row.props.uuid}) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, $type as type with params {type=node, rows=[{nodeRef=-7, props={mustUseProjectForReports=null, roundingAmountPauseEndTime=null, allowAutoPauseOverwrite=null, minReportPauseLength=null, dateFormat=null, minReportLength=null, roundingTypeReportStartTime=null, language=null, ownerId=null, uuid=12c38bf2-23ea-40d1-b799-c00044c5027f, allowReportsToTime=null, sumLeaveLTEOvertimePool=null, availableUserRoles=null, hardwareTerminalId=null, isLicensePartner=null, stripeSubscriptionId=null, apiUrl=null, warningTypeReportClocking=null, registrationSourceType=null, logo=null, clientSecret=null, userLimit=null, reportTypeStrategy=null, roundingAmountReportStartTime=null, timeZone=null, overtimeCorrectionAmount=null, settingsInheritanceStrategy=null, sumVacationLTEVacationPool=null, locationRadius=null, allowReportsFromTime=null, macAddress=null, legalTermsAcceptDate=null, approvalNotifications=null, onlyFullDayVacation=null, roundingTypePauseEndTime=null, roundingAmountReportEndTime=null, numberEmployees=null, expirationTime=null, unique=null, userUuid=f00e48cc-7f31-4df3-b1f7-3b3eb1ce971e, hardwareTerminalLimit=null, subdomain=null, pckg=null, locationTracking=false, roundingTypePauseStartTime=null, allowAccountProfiles=null, stripeCustomerId=null, status=null, displayName=Sub-project #3 [edited], defaultCompanyOwnerActions=null, creatorId=f00e48cc-7f31-4df3-b1f7-3b3eb1ce971e, warningForClockingReport=null, description=test, hasAllInclusiveContract=null, reportPauseLengthProblem=null, allowPaidPausesInReports=null, ssid=null, roundingTypeReportEndTime=null, promoExpirationTime=null, numberFormat=null, trialTime=null, autoCreateReports=null, wageTypeStrategy=null, minVacationLength=null, maxDailyReportLength=null, promoCode=null, secondaryType=7, clientId=null, roundingAmountPauseStartTime=null, maxReportLength=null, promoCodeRaw=null, additionalUserNumber=null, onlyClockingReports=null, availableLoginMethods=null, unique3=null, unique1=null, defaultCompanyActions=null, unique2=null, allowReportsInFuture=null, highlightTargetTimeDifferences=null, creatorCompanyId=28cd0998-6073-4773-992a-d6cdd9d8cdc6, warningForClockingDay=null, vacationCorrectionAmount=null, isEnabledPayroll=null, allowReportsInPast=null, createTime=null, maxReportPauseLength=null, payMethodType=null, timeFormat=null, maxVacationLength=null, sepaDebitSourceId=null}}]}
```

Comment: Hi there! Would it be possible to share Spring Data Neo4j debug logs? See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/5.3.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference:testing:log-levels as an example configuration

Comment: @Rolf, I added neo4j logs to the initial description.